# Limit the number of options returned in the BelongsTo select field for a Laravel Nova resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am trying to limit the number of statuses returned in the `BelongsTo` select for a `Set` resource. My status table uses a `parent_id` to determine what statuses are grouped together.

When I create a new set, I would expect to see only the statuses in the related model, but instead all the statuses in the table are loaded.

I have tried using [`fillUsing`](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html#field-hydration) and [`displayUsing`](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/fields.html?#field-resolution-formatting) to narrow the results but that has not worked.

Below is the relevant source.

### Nova Resource - Set

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),
        BelongsTo::make(__('Status'), 'status'),
    ];
}
```

### Eloquent Model - Set

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Status::class)
        ->where('parent_id', 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out an hour after posting.

You nee to override the `indexQuery` function on your Nova Resource - Set

```
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->where('parent_id', 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For laravel nova v4, you can override the following static pro in your resource:

```php
public static $relatableSearchResults = 25;
```

Documentation: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/relationships.html#limiting-relation-results